# How can we get the access token from Instagram

Tags: java, instagram, instagram-api

I need to write a application in Java which searches media from Instagram. My application is not a web application and runs as a standalone java process. We need to search for Photos which match a certain criteria and we intend to solve the following queries.

```
e.g
a. photos from a certain geo location (city | state | country | zipCode | lat/long)
b. photos under a certain category (e.g. entertainment, sports)
```

Since my application is neither web application nor mobile app. How can we get the access token to be used in my application?

Is it possible to get the access token by providing clientId, clientSecret, userName and password?

Answer (score 1):

You will require browser interaction for retrieving an access token. The most simple way for your use case would be something like this:

1. [Register](https://www.instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/) a new client with Instagram, use `http://localhost` as URLs. In the "Security" tab, **uncheck** "Disable implicit OAuth".
2. Open the client-side authentication URL in your browser:
   `https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=token` (use the `CLIENT-ID` and `REDIRECT-URI` from step 1, do not forget to encode your URL, e.g. `http://localhost` becomes `http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost`).
3. Enter your credentials and submit
4. You will be redirected to a localhost URL. Ignore your browser's error message that no connection could be established. The URL input should be something like `http://localhost/#access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN` -- this is your access token.

Comment: This is a workaround that shouldn't be needed. Instagram apparently doesn't like Server to server use-cases. This is obviously nothing against the clear explanation of you qqilihq.